# How to access nested data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I write a SQL procedure which showing given output.How to access data in php using foreach loop ?

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [vehical_profile_id] => 1
                        [chasis_number] => 123
                        [vehicle_engine_number] => a123
                        [rto_regis_number] => a123
                        [model_number] => a123
                        [vehicle_color] => red
                        [vehicle_production_year_month] => june 2012
                        [owner_first_name] => avinash
                        [owner_middle_name] => prakash
                        [owner_last_name] => dhanke
                        [owner_father_name] => prakash dhanke
                        [owner_gender] => male
                        [owner_blood_group] => AB+
                        [owner_dob] => 1990-07-07
                        [entity_address] => wadi
                        [entity_local_area] => navneet nagar
                        [entity_city] => nagpur
                        [entity_state] => mh
                        [entity_country] => india
                        [entity_pincode] => 440023
                        [mobile] => 973044444
                        [landline] => 
                        [email] => prajakta@gmail.com
                        [vehicle_service_profile_id] => 1
                        [vehicle_id] => 1
                        [vehicle_service_in_date] => 2014-11-19
                        [vehicle_service_out_date] => 0000-00-00
                        [vehicle_service_status] => NOT DONE
                        [vehicle_service_job_card_no] => job123
                        [vehicle_service_receipt_no] => r123
                        [vehicle_service_total_cost] => 5000
                    )

            )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [vehicle_service_details_id] => 1
                    [vehicle_service_profile_id] => 1
                    [vehicle_service_work_code] => OILCHANGE
                    [vehicle_service_work_status] => NOT DONE
                    [vehicle_service_work_cost] => 5000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [vehicle_service_details_id] => 2
                    [vehicle_service_profile_id] => 1
                    [vehicle_service_work_code] => BREAKSHOES
                    [vehicle_service_work_status] => NOT DONE
                    [vehicle_service_work_cost] => 2000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [vehicle_service_details_id] => 3
                    [vehicle_service_profile_id] => 1
                    [vehicle_service_work_code] => HEADLIGHT
                    [vehicle_service_work_status] => NOT DONE
                    [vehicle_service_work_cost] => 1000
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `foreach($array as $something) {}` to access everything (you'd need an inset foreach to loop around all the child nodes). Or; `foreach($array[0] as $something) {}` to access the first node and `foreach($array[1] as $something) {}` to access the second node.

Comment: hd, that is static approach, the  $array[0] is like access just one element of the array, this is why I have stored the results in another array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $FinalArray=array();
   foreach($array as $valueArrayone){
    foreach($valueArrayone as $valueArrayTwo){
   // valueArrayTwoWILL BE THE 3rd nested array, this is how you can access it   but you need to take     care of the nesting 
    $finalArray[]= $valueArrayTwo; <--- you can assign that array to final array and can iterate over it
    }
  }
  print_r($finalArray);
```

I hope it would work smoothly.